# Verifying and Formatting Text before importing it to MySql

Tags: mysql, regex, csv, lazarus

I have an issue importing some CSV/TXT files.

Here at the company we receive files from other sources (companies). Some of these files sometimes come partially broken.

For example, a file containing 6 columns (id, name, city, state, zipCode, phone) and 2 million lines. The first 10.000 lines of that file are OK. But in the middle of the file instead of 6 columns, it has 5 or even 7 columns.

It seems like somebody "merged" several files into this one and did not pay attention to the number of columns. So when I import it to my MySql database table, the data comes very messy due to the columns being broken. The zipCode records show up on the field state and so on.

I was wondering how to scan such file before importing it to my DB, something like counting the ";" delimiters of each line. Would it be done using Regex or what would be the best option for that?

My program is written in Lazarus/Pascal.

Answer (score 1):

I would read the file line by line and check the columns.

- If a line respects the expected columns (count, , copy it in another file (`input_OK.csv`).
- If it doesn't dump it in a broken lines file (`input_KO.csv`).

Study input_KO.csv errors, correct them then import the corrected file into the database.

IMO, a regex will take long here.